# what is the diffrence between GIS and GPS?

Tags: gis

Is GPS one of the application of GIS?

And is there any sw create gps for a specific location ( I determine it)?

thank you

Comment: Your very brief and a bit obscure question, I reckon you should rather read about GIS and GPS in Wikipedia first, so you become more familiar, thus will be able to refine your question.

Answer (score 8):

You could think of GPS as a tool for *collecting* location data. Which would be then 'passed' for further use: by your smartphone using location to recomend restaurant, by a logger on migratory animal recording their travel or by tracking vehicle mapping new roundabout in your neighbourhood, which you will later see in Google Maps.

Once collected, by GPS or any other method, spatial data would then probably land in spatially enabled DB where they could be *managed*, *accessed* and *analysed* by GIS: by, for instance, adding topology, connectivity and driving directions for the roundabout or calculating time and distance of animal migration.

Comment: Excelent answer. Wouldn't dare to bet my Bachelor in GeoScience that I could provide a better one!

Answer (score 4):

**GPS**: The Global Positioning System is a network of satellites that orbits around the earth at let a receiver device determine its location, speed, direction, and time. The receiver device (which is commonly known as "GPS") needs to be connected to at least 4 satellites to determine its location, and hence speed, direction and time. GPS is an American system, and it's the only completely implemented global navigation satellite system. There are other GNSS like Russian [GLONASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS), European [Galileo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_positioning_system), the proposed Chinese [COMPASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMPASS_navigation_system), and Indian [IRNSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Regional_Navigational_Satellite_System). GPS devices are now widely, not just used but also, integrated into other devices like cars, smart phones, and cameras.

**Geographic Information System (GIS)** is the implementation of database for spatial data. If a database can have text, numbers, dates, and photos, it can have maps as well. It's not just about the location, it's about querying the location and analyzing that location with respect to other locations. It's just like querying and analyzing tabular data. The only difference is that if a picture is worth a thousand words, a map is worth a thousand pictures.

GIS is a mix of science (Geography), information systems, and modern software technologies